# Positioning div in the middle of parent div over other sibling divs

Tags: html, css

I have this div structure:

```
<div id="outer-div">
    <div id="first-div"></div>
    <div id="cell-icon">anFAicon</div>
</div>
```

and the style:

```
#outer-div {
  height:80px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#first-div {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  border-right: 2px solid #619e38
}
#cell-icon {
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

this will output:

[image]

see here: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/RZgwvd

What I need is this:

[image]

I want to place the div cell-icon in the middle of the outer-div over the other div(s). Tried with position absolute but it doesn't work, as you can see above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

```css
#outer-div {
  height:80px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
#first-div {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  border-right: 2px solid #619e38
}
#cell-icon {
  border:1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
    <div id="first-div"></div>
    <div id="cell-icon">anFAicon</div>
</div>
```

### What I Changed

Firstly, I added `position: relative` to your `#outer-div` CSS. This is so that when you use absolute positioning later, the element is constrained within the `#outer-div` container, rather than the body (elements are positioned relative to the closest parent with a position value of either `absolute` or `relative`).

Then, I simply added `left: 50%` to the `#cell-icon` element to move it left by 50%, and then `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` to [move the div into the exact centre](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Finally, I've added a `background-color` of white and `z-index` of `1` (as suggested in the comments section) to position the `#cell-icon` element above the other two divs (as is shown in your diagram).

Comment: At least explain why his code isn't working (instead of just feeding him the code directly).

Comment: To complete the answer I would add this to #cell-icon:  z-index: 1;
    background-color: white; this way the line does not mix with the box

Comment: @Lucke Thanks for your suggestion - I have added it to this post.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `.cell-icon` isn't moving is because you need to put `position: relative` on its parent element (`#outer-div`). See below:

```
#outer-div {
    height:80px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pseudo selector :before and :after` to draw that `line` between divs, add `position:relative` to parent div which is `#outer-div` here to make `position:absolute` element relative to parent div.

```css
#outer-div {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first-div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#cell-icon {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#outer-div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 75%;
  background: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#outer-div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 75%;
  background: green;
  bottom: -75%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="first-div"></div>
  <div id="cell-icon">anFAicon</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @neptune This creates perfect line at top and bottom, you can reduce it's height to get spacing between centered aligned icon. Reduce height in :after and :before selectors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, then I think this is not possible with CSS while keeping child element positioning absolute.

If an element has an absolute position, then it will consider height and width according to browser dimension. So child element dimension can not alter with its parents.

If `position:absolute` is necessary for you then you can use javascript to find height of its parents and then apply it to child element accordingly.

Alternative to absolute postion you can use `float:left/float:right` and use `margin` property to get result.

You can use following code:

```
#outer-div {
   height: 80px;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
#first-div {
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   border-right: 2px solid #619e38;
   float: left;
}
#cell-icon {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: -35px;
   margin-top: 28px;
}
```

Set margin to make it proper.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who would who fail exact positioning in css, javascript may be a resort. This code intends to size the 'modal' element to overlap a 'parent' element. Using css same as the "modal" example by [Toastrackenigma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45608967/4299943) above

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent_id");
var modal = document.getElementById("modal_id");

var rect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();

modal.style.position = 'absolute';
modal.style.left =  (rect.left + window.scrollX) + 'px';
modal.style.top = (rect.top + window.scrollY) + 'px';
modal.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
modal.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
```

If a class needs to be added to an element to indicate activity..

```
parent.classList.add("loading");
```

..and class removed when done:

```
parent.classList.remove("loading");
```